# Using temporary tables in SSIS flow fails

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an ETL process which extracts ~40 tables from a source database (Oracle 10g) to a SQL Server (2014 developer edition) Staging environment.  My process for extraction:

1. Determine newest row in staging
2. Select all newer rows from source
3. Insert results into #TEMPTABLE
4. Merge results from #TEMPTABLE to Staging

This works on a package by package basis both from Visual Studio locally and executing from SSISDB on the SQL Server.

However I am grouping my Extract jobs into one master package for ease of execution and flow to the transform stage.  Only approximately 5 of my packages use temporary tables, the others are all trunc and load, but wanted to move some more to this method.  When i run the master package anything using a temporary table fails. Because of pretty large log files, its hard to pinpoint the actual error but so far all it tells me is that the #TEMPTABLE can't be found and/or the status is VS_ISBROKEN.

Things i have tried:

1. Set all relevant components to `delay validation = false`
2. Master package has `ExecuteOutOfProcess = true`
3. Increased my tempdb capacity far exceeding my needs

A thought i had was the `RetainSameConnection = true` on my Staging database connection - could this be the cause?  I would try to create separate connections for each, but assumed the `ExecuteOutOfProcess` would take care of this for me.

---

EDIT

I created the following scenario:

- Package A (Master package containing Execute Package Task references only)

  - Package B (Uses temp tables)
  - Package C (No temp tables)

Executing Package B on it's own completes successfully.  All temp table usage is contained within this package - there is no requirement for Package C to see the temp table created by Package B.

Executing Package C completes successfully.

Executing Package A, C completes successfully, B fails.

---

UPDATE

The workaround was to create a package level connection for each package that uses temporary tables, thus ensuring that each package held its own connection.  I have raised a connect issue with Microsoft as i believe that as the parent package opens the connection it should inherit and retain throughout any child packages.

Comment: Temporary tables are temporary. That means, they disappear once you close the connection. Why do you use temporary tables if you are in the staging environment anyway?

Comment: I am using temporary tables because i dont want to use `OleDbCommand` objects to perform updates on a row by row basis.  I drop new rows into a temp table and then issue a merge to update the staging table - i am happy that they disappear after the job is finished

Comment: They disappear when the *connection* closes, not when the job is finished. The connection will close when you move from one dataflow to the next, or when you move from the SQL script that created the table to then next script or flow. Which is why the package is broken - there is no table there to bind to or validate.

Comment: Correct - exactly what my requirements are, and as stated this works perfectly on a one by one basis - just when i try to execute multiple at a time the failures occur

Comment: What you call "correct" *is* the problem. You can't expect a temporary table to be there when you move to the next step

Comment: What is exactly error message for Package B execution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several suggestions to your case.

1. Set *RetainSameCoonection=true*. This will allow you to work safely with TEMP tables in SSIS packages.
2. Would not use *ExecuteOutOfProcess*, it will increase your RAM footprint since every Child pack will start in its process, and decrease performance - add process start lag. This used in 32-bit environments to overcome 2 GB limit, but on x64 it is no longer necessary.
   Child package execution does not inherit connection object instances from its Parent, so the same connection will not be spanned across all of your Child packages.
3. SSIS Packages with Temp table operations are more difficult to debug (less obvious), so pay attention to testing.

Comment: Ref your point 2, it seems that project level connections with `retain same connection` do not span the child packages - or the first package to use it closes it?  I am not sure why though?  After all it is a project level connection - could be a bug?

Comment: @DomCotton, Project Level Connection is just a container with connection properties. Connection itself is instantiated with package start; does not matter whether it is Parent or Child. Physically Connection is retained in Package execution, that is why you cannot use same retained connection as a source and a destination in DFT. Once Package execution is over - connections are closed and opened again in the next Package run.

Comment: So it seems... i would have expected that as its one connection (retain) and the parent is opening it, i thought each package would say "Its open and set to retain so i will just use it".  I have created a package level connection for each - getting a new error now :S  Thanks

Comment: Following on from this, you state child package execution does not inherit connection objects, but they do inherit transactions - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms141083(v=sql.120).aspx - surely that requires some inheritance of the connection?

Comment: @DomCotton, your link describes _standard SSIS transactions_ with MSDTC. It is used when you set _TransactionOption=Required_. Using MS SQL Transactions with _RetainSameConnection_ instead of MSDTC is a workaround on MSDTC Transactions, limitations and performance.