# When to use global Temp table in SSIS over Local temp table?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When to use global Temp table in SSIS over Local temp table ? I know the difference in terms of SQL usage but when it comes to implement in SSIS which one to prefer in which scenario ?

Comment: The answer to most questions of the form "should I be global or local" is "be local when you can, global if you have to".

Comment: Out of interest, why use either?

Comment: @Larnu- Well there can be various reasons like you don't have access to create physical tables and still want to access some set of data generated from higher task to lower task.

Comment: I assume that you are using SSIS to import data from a file to a table.  Then you will use the data in that table to Insert/Update/Delete data in other tables.  Is this what you are doing?

Comment: @JasonGeiger - I am not doing any load as of now. I just wanted to know in which case we should use global temp in terms of SSIS. May be any scenario ?

Comment: @RajneeshVaishwar - I wouldn't ever use a global temp table for SSIS.  It would either be local or I would import into a real table and continue processing it outside of SSIS (or with other SSIS packages).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Little theory recap for MS SQL temp tables:

- Global temp table - you create it, fill/select, delete it. Table remains in TempDB and is deleted when all users that are referencing the table disconnect from the instance of SQL Server. Table is accessible by other connections/sessions.
- Local temp table - you create it and can use within your connection session. Table is dropped automatically when you close connection session.

So if you need to store something just for your scope, Local tables are better, since it is deleted automatically as you close the session. Global tables are better if you need to pass data between sessions/processes. Drawback of Global Temp tables - you have to ensure it does not exist when you create it, drop when you are done etc.

Regarding temp tables and SSIS. SSIS usually opens a new connection for each operation with DB - **Execute SQL** Task. In data flow, it opens a **new connection** for **each component**. Therefore, local Temp table will be accessible only in one Task/Data Flow component. In such session pattern you have the following options:

- Use Local temp tables within one command of *Execute SQL* task. Another task means another connection, local temp tables are dropped.
- Use Global temp tables and check table existence when creating, delete table afterwards etc.
- Use Local temp tables and set `RetainSameConnection=true` property of related Connection Manager. This setting means that SSIS does not drop connection after execution of *Execute SQL* task. In some cases SSIS still might open another connection. More details how to use it - see [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37945772/1010622).

Comment: How are you able to use a Global temp table across multiple tasks without `RetainSameConnection=true`? Because when SSIS executes the next task, SQL will destroy the global temp table because no one is referencing the global temp table.